# Keep subtracting value in loop getting mysql result php

Tags: php, mysql

I have an mysql table named example.

```
 Id   | Amount  | Left | Filled
 1    |  1      |  1   | 0
 2    |  4      |  4   | 0
 5    |  7      |  7   | 0
```

I have an variable named `$var = 9`
Now I have an array named `$array` with those ids as `array([0] => 1, [1] => 2, [2] => 5)` Which itself is a mysql result.
How do I make a loop so that ids in array keep subtracting the left and keep filling as per the amount but within the total value of `$var` so that my end result in table is

```
 Id   | Amount  | Left | Filled
 1    |  1      |  0   | 1
 2    |  4      |  0   | 4
 5    |  7      |  3   | 4
```

Comment: How come `5` isn't `0` and `7` for `Left` and `Filled`? I don't understand the logic.

Comment: As the amount asked is 9 in `$var` So it needs to keep looping and subtracting till value 0 in ascending order. So at last for ID 5 filled is 4

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes But can't understand how to loop like that

Answer (score 0):

You can use while loop in order to loop on the ids and reduce the amount in each iteration.

I am not sure  how you access your DB so I leave it pseudo.

Consider the following code:

```
$ids = array(1,2,5);
$value = 9;

function reduceAmount($id, $value) {
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM example WHERE Id='$id'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);     
    $take = min($row['Left'], $value); // the amount you can take (not more then what left)

    $left = $row['Left'] - $take;
    $filled = $row['Filled'] + $take;
    $conn->query("UPDATE example SET Left='$left', Filled='$filled' WHERE Id='$id'")
    return max(0, $value - $take);
}

while ($value > 0 && !empty($ids)) { // check if value still high and the options ids not finish
    $id = array_shift($ids); //get first ID
    $value = reduceAmount($id, $value);
}
```

You can check at the end of the loop if `value` still bigger then 0 - this can happen when no enough "Amount" in `ids`

Comment: How do you fetch element from DB? with `mysql_query`? `mysql_fetch_array`?

Comment: mysql_query? Crikey, let's hopes not!

Comment: mysqli I mean  .

Comment: Please give me example of how you fetch something from you DB

Comment: `$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                    $gg[] = $rows[0];
                   }`

Comment: @ZoooccRefback Updated with `mysqli_query`

Comment: No, I found my own way : )

Comment: @ZoooccRefback If so, please post it here as answer so other may learn from it